# Store promotion path environment for use in multiple YAML pipelines (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

We are trying to split out our platform in a more microservice like architecture and want to reduce code duplication in our YAML pipelines. The idea is each microservice would have its own YAML pipeline for deployment.

We are trying to store our list of environments outside of any individual YAML pipeline so that if a new environment is needed we only need to add a reference to this in one place, the same if we want to remove an existing environment. something similar to the image below.

[image: Basic idea]

I have tried to use a Variable group in Azure DevOps however the "Each" Keyword used for creating YAML loops is only setup to work with parameters of type "object", and although I can loop through a parameter I do not know how to pull the parameter values from a central location.

Is there a way to achieve what I am describing?